# Combining multiple columns into single column

Tags: sql

I changed my questions.

I have a data looks like this:

> ```
> | rs1 | rs2 | rs3 | rs4 |
> | rs5 | rs6 | rs7 | rs8 |
> ```

I've used this codes:

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, col4 AS col1
FROM 58c_11
ORDER BY 1
```

It's output is like this:

> ```
> | rs1rs2rs3rs4 |
> | rs5rs6rs7rs8 |
> ```

I intend to do it like this:

> ```
> | rs1 | 
> | rs2 | 
> | rs3 | 
> | rs4 |
> | rs5 | 
> | rs6 |
> | rs7 |
> | rs8 |
> ```

Comment: Please show the original columns in a tabular format and explain what the output is.

Comment: Can you post your actual sample data?

Comment: Only GOD can answer this question :)

Comment: Your question has been downvoted because it is unclear, and you are wasting people's time. As the comments above ask, we need to see the data as it is in the table before the query. We can't tell by looking at the sample output what values  come from where and why the result you get is incorrect. If you can fix the question and clarify it, we may be able to help.

Comment: Do you want something like `select col1 from 58c_11 union all select col2 from 58c_11 union all select col3 from 58c_11` etc? It seems strange that you would want to push all your columns together like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please always write question in detail, if really need someone to assist you.

You can use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), it takes the columns and converts it into rows. I have created sample query which will convert columns into rows.

```
select value
FROM tmp

unpivot
(
  value
  for tmp in (col1,col2,col3,col4)
) u
```

Created Sample query on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e00c1/4)

Let me know if you have any question.

Thanks
Suresh